# Careers Bug: Removing a Relocate To location removes all of them

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to My Profile page.
2. Click "Edit" for the candidate info line (eg `Active candidate interested in full-time position. Willing to relocate.`)
3. <s>Check "I'm willing to relocate".</s> This isn't required.
4. Click "Add Location" under "If so, where?" at least twice.
5. Enter values into one or more of the text fields. (Not required)
6. Click the "Remove" link for one of the text fields. All of the text fields under "If so, where?" will be removed instead of just the one you wanted.

Expected behavior: Only the text field next to the clicked "Remove" link should be removed, all others should remain.

Actual behavior: All text fields for "If so, where?" are removed.

(note that the "I have the legal right to work here immediately" checkboxes are included, I just didn't want to have to write it out in each step.)

Comment: Ugh. Stand by, fix coming shortly...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed! Thanks for pointing this out.